# Авто заполнения php кода в visual studio code

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

У меня такая проблема - Я работаю в vs-code с языком php. Раньше, работая в sublime text я могу просто вписать "php" и нажать таб, после чего у меня раскрывался тег php. В vs-code такого сделать не получается. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В VSCode это работает иначе. Из коробки такой подсказки нет и вы должны добавить ее вручную.

Откройте `File - Preferences - User snippets` и выберите файл настроек для нужного языка, например, plaintext.

Добавьте туда следующий код перед закрывающей фигурной скобкой:

```
"php" : {
        "prefix": "php",
        "body": [
        "<?php $1 ?>"
        ],
    "description": "Expand PHP Tags"
}
```

Сохраните настройки и перезапустите VSCode. После этого подсказка будет работать.

Comment: [ссылка](https://imgur.com/a/2W9wBIv) сделал все как вы сказали, пару раз это сработало, но почему то позже перестало показывать подсказку на сниппет

Comment: Переписал все в глобальный файл со сниппетами. Все заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, как вариант